# How to check if filtered recyclerView result is null?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Actually i have a filter method in my recyclerView adapter and when there is no item in the arraylist the recyclerView just hide and i would to show an alert instead of just showing no item.

How can i detect when filter return no item found?

Here is the filter method from adapter

```
   @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                final FilterResults oReturn = new FilterResults();
                final ArrayList<ItemModel> results = new ArrayList<>();
                if (mFilteredList == null)
                    mFilteredList = new ArrayList<>(variantiConstructors);
                if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                    if (mFilteredList != null && mFilteredList.size() > 0) {
                        for (final ItemModel cd : mFilteredList) {
                            if (cd.getCodiceArticolo().toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                                results.add(cd);
                        }
                    }
                    oReturn.values = results;
                    oReturn.count = results.size(); //newly Aded by ZA
                } else {
                    oReturn.values = mFilteredList;
                    oReturn.count = mFilteredList.size(); //newly added by ZA
                }
                return oReturn;
            }

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(final CharSequence constraint,
                                          FilterResults results) {
                variantiConstructors = new ArrayList<>((ArrayList<ItemModel>) results.values);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
```

And here is where i'm calling it

```
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        itemAdapter.getFilter().filter(edtSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase());
        Log.e("COUNT",String.valueOf(itemAdapter.getItemCount()));
    }
```

Comment: In your `publishResults()` function, you can add a `if` to check `results.size`. If it equals 0, you can display an alert. Otherwise, update your RecyclerView

Comment: try to initialize the fitered list and check the list size> 0 not null or not , to avoid nullpointerException

Comment: @cesarmarch results.size is not a function.. i was trying to check results.values but nothing it still count all items

Answer (score -1, accepted):

instead of checking for result.values or result.count i had to check if variantiConstructor.isEmpty as result was returning in any case true.

So in the adapter i'm using now the following code to show an alert when there are no items found

```
        protected void publishResults(final CharSequence constraint,
                                      FilterResults results) {

                variantiConstructors = new ArrayList<>((ArrayList<ItemModel>) results.values);
                if(variantiConstructors.isEmpty()){
                    Alerts.alertError("NO","",mContext);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```